# where is this d3 code executed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I was reviewing the following code below from https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js today.  It occurred to me that all the d3 code is variable statements; nothing seems to "invoke" it and say "now use these variable definitions to draw me svg objects".  So my question is: where does that invocation occur.  Is the invocation in the d3.min.js code? Or is it something about the way the var statements are defined, or something else?  Thanks for your help with this fundamental question.

Also yes: I did try to google-and-reason out for myself for an hour or so. I'd never post here after that if it weren't a last resort.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>   
<script>
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                 { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                         .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                   .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key I think to what you are wanting to get to, is the 'append' method.

If you take this partial line for example...

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

d3 has found the 'body' element, and now it has created a new 'svg element.

You will then see another similar line...

```
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
```

We now have a 'path' added inside of the svg.

The 'lineFunction' created earlier, was a function that will basically return the values for the path coordinates (you can give it a function that returns a value, as opposed to just a value), which is pretty much it. The rest are just attributes for the respective elements.

Comment: Thank you.  Putting the above answers together, I get that: (1) JS will execute the code on page load, if there are no other events that tie its execution to events (2) in this code, the append method causes svg elements to be drawn.  One helpful experiment for me was to take reduce the "Var lineGraph ..." line to just "svgContainer.append("path") .." and I found that everything still executed.  That behavior fit my expectations better.  It's weird that code consisting only of variable defs will be executed to make something, but I'll adjust my understanding over time.

Comment: Why is it weird though ? The variable def is calling a method. Eg, suppose my code is     var result = doLoadsOfStuffAndReturnCalculatedResult();   is relatively normal. However, I do think d3 involves a slight shift in thinking in general though, so I think its good for you to experiment with the code, as it helps programming overall to see slightly different philosophies in code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Your question is more about how Javascript works. As the name suggest Javascript is a scripting language.

Depending upon what you want your JavaScript code to do and how you structured it, it will either execute as soon as the file loads or wait for a triggering event (like a click, or load).

Unlike compiled languages JS execute the code statement by statement.

So to answer your question. Since there are no events in the above code, browser starts to execute your code the moment it sees the code.

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line() is a function and browser evaluates it when it encounter it.
```

I have tried to explain it in very simple terms, if you have any more questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

what's in `<script>` tags is executed.

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
```

means call the method d3.svg.line and return the results to lineFunction